# Why does the Linux kernel have its own bootloader

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, grub, boot-loader, assembly

I am trying to work my way through Linux kernel code, and in [this file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/header.S) there seems to be a full blown bootloader that bios is expected to run. I was under the impression that generally, grub will be in the mbr and then it will somehow invoke the kernel.

My questions are:

1. why is there (to the best of my knowledge) a built in bootloader in the kernel? Is this for historical reasons?
2. Can someone explain step by step what happens from pressing the power button to starting the kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it’s for historical reasons: it used to be possible to write the kernel to a floppy disk, and boot a PC using that. `header.S` still provides a boot sector so that the kernel can display a message if someone tries this.

   `header.S` also provides a PE header if the kernel is configured with a UEFI boot loader; the resulting kernel image can then be booted directly from UEFI. In all cases, `header.S` provides a header implementing the multiboot protocol, which is what Grub etc. use to start the kernel.
2. On current x86 systems without a BMC, the system controller starts, initialises the CPU, which runs the system firmware. That initialises memory, the various buses and so on, then looks for a disk with an appropriate system partition. It loads the chosen or default boot loader (*e.g.* Grub) from that partition. The boot loader then loads the kernel and initramfs (usually), and [hands off control to the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arch/x86/boot.html).

   There’s a lot more to it than that; see [this description of the EFI boot process](http://jdebp.uk/FGA/efi-boot-process.html) (ignoring the section on `ELILO`, which isn’t used now). There’s also a description on [the Debian wiki UEFI page](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Booting_a_UEFI_machine_normally), which also explains how removable media are handled.

Comment: So where does grub jump to in the kernel once it is loaded?

Comment: That depends, see [this kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arch/x86/boot.html) for details (I’ve added it to the answer as well).